# Windows Services and the Main thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-3.5, windows-services

I'm writing a Windows Service in .NET 3.5.
The typical programming model for a windows service is to override the `OnStart` method to assemble your classes before initiating any long-running processes on another thread.

This is because the `OnStart` event must return after a default of 30 seconds before a timeout.

In my scenario this thread is vitally important and so I want to create some form of heartbeat system to monitor its state and recycle / recreate it if necessary.

Ideally I would perform this heartbeat check from the main application thread (because the heartbeat must never die) but I do not see how I can marshal any new calls onto that thread.

How would you solve this problem?
Perhaps my intended approach is wrong? If so, how else would you approach it?

Comment: "In my scenario this thread is vitally important and so I want to create some form of heartbeat system to monitor its state and recycle / recreate it if necessary." - which thread? what are you trying to monitor/recycle/recreate?

Comment: As stated - a new thread is created in OnStart which initiates the main work of the Windows Service (amongst other things it hosts a WCF service).

Comment: In OnStart, create your monitoring thread. From that thread, create the worker thread and monitor the worker thread's IsAlive property to check if the thread has terminated normally or abnormally. You need to catch exceptions from the worker thread on the worker thread to make sure the Windows service doesn't crash. Is this what you're currently doing?

Comment: Why might the thread need recreation/whatever?  Can you provide more details on what that thread does. how it gets into the state where it is not able to do its job and what that state is, (is it looping, blocked, terminated, what?).